# How to transfer a texture to a resampled mesh?

Tags: 3d, 3d-graphics, 3d-modeling

I have two OBJ files, which contain a mesh that describes the same shape. One has ~10k vertices, and has texture coordinates. The other has ~5k vertices, and doesn't have texture coordinates.

How do I transfer the texture coordinates to the second mesh quickly, without having to unwrap the texture again?

Preferrably I'd use some open source software like Blender or a dedicated script. But if there is an easy solution with proprietary software I'll find a way to access that.

Answer (score 0):

You only need one .obj model for to automatically create the anaglyph

Take a look at http://paulbourke.net/stereographics/anaglyph if you want to know how this can be handle
(you can find at the end my contribution for to handle anaglyphs with .obj files)

Comment: How does an anaglyph help transfer tex coords?

Answer (score 0):

Absent UV info (texture coordinates) you'll have a lot of trouble.

Many 3D DCC tools (I think Blender included) allow for multi-resolution sculpting, which is based on having both high and low poly versions of a mesh - one "bakes" the higher-resolution mesh and its applied textures into new texture maps for the lower resolution mesh, but adding in the baking process vector normal, normal, displacement and bump maps, which result in a lower polycount mesh that *looks* higher-res in game due to the normal and disp maps being applied to it.

As a result, all calcs in game which are polycount dependent (animation, physics, realtime lighting) are far more efficicent, but the aesthetics are still pretty strong.

but that is based on both the higher and lower poly meshes being properly UVd.